# Get comma separated data in oracle forms

Tags: sql, oracle, split, oracleforms

I have a field `orderno` having data in format

```
"PUR/0012/17-18","PUR/0013/17-18"
```

I want to fetch distinct `orderno` which are separated by comma

Query I used is

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('PUR/0012/17-18','PUR/0013/17-18','[^,]+', 15, LEVEL) 
FROM dual
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR('PUR/0012/17-18','PUR/0013/17-18', '[^,]+', 15, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL )
```

But it is showing error.

Comment: How many CSV terms are in each string, and could you post a larger sample data set?

Comment: Please finally learn to format your posts.

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: Never store values as csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things I can think of.

The first one is obvious - query you wrote is invalid. Should be

```
SQL> SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('PUR/0012/17-18,PUR/0013/17-18','[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) result
  2  FROM dual
  3  CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR('PUR/0012/17-18,PUR/0013/17-18', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;

RESULT
-----------------------------
PUR/0012/17-18
PUR/0013/17-18

SQL>
```

Once you fix it, but if it still doesn't work, is the fact that you didn't mention Oracle Forms version you use; maybe it is one of versions which doesn't support regular expressions. If that's the case, you should create a **stored** function which would return a desired result into a form. As all the *calculation* is performed in the database, it'll work.